# import geopandas works in cmd but not in Python

Tags: python, geopandas

I installed GeoPandas on my computer and can import it in cmd.

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import geopandas
>>>
```

but in Python I get this error

```
>>> import geopandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
>>>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is "cmd" vs "python". You probably have two Python installations on your machine, and one has geopandas installed and the other one not. But I don't understand from this question what "but in python I get this error" means. Both examples you show are Python interactive interpreter prompts.

Comment: @farzad_632003 a bit more detail about how you installed and os that you are using will be helpful. are you on windows or linux? what this code are you trying? how did you invoke python?

If you are invoking python from cmd I can guarantee high likelihood you can't import geopandas; it's hard to install it with pip.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to my problem and finally managed to solve it. I added in environment variables the "PYTHONPATH" variable with value "C:\Users(my username)" and now I can import geopandas from python IDLE.